# Вконтакте лайкнуть фото python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте, selenium

Как лайкнуть но не комментарии к фотографии. И не лайкать если уже лайкнул, и на любой фотографии в исходном коде есть список всех фотографии. Можно ли их лайкнуть не переходя на них рандомно. Как получить количетство лайкой для данной фотографии и если к примеру количество лайков данной фотографии > 10, то лайкнуть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    def like_foto_():
        driver.get(link_now)
        print('Ожидание загрузки страницы...')
        time.sleep(wait_1 + 2)
        html = driver.page_source
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id('page_avatar_wrap')  # glawnaja foto
        # driver.find_element_by_id('profile_photo_link')#glawnaja foto
        # buf = re.findall('<a class="page_counter" href="(.*?)"', html)#wse fotki "/albums482677829?profile=1" https://vk.com/zhoser?z=albums4826905
        print('Ожидание загрузки фото...')
        time.sleep(wait_1 + 2)
        html = driver.page_source


except Exception as exc:
print(exc)
traceback.print_exc()
print('не нажал page_avatar_wrap открыть фото')
html = driver.page_source
# если эту фотку уже лайкал
buf = re.findall('" onclick="return showPhoto(\'(.*?)\',', html)
print('ссылки на фото: ' + str(buf))
buf = re.findall('like_btn like _like   animate active(.*?)"', html)

driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Нравится')[0].click()
time.sleep(wait_1)
print('Лайкнул скорее всего')

print('лайкнул ли это фото = ' + str(buf[0]))
print('all_foto_likes[0]=' + str(all_foto_likes[0]))

all_foto_likes = re.findall('data-count="(.*?)"', html)
print('all_foto_likes[0]=' + str(all_foto_likes[0]))
```

Comment: Оффтоп. А почему не использовать vk api? Например, https://vk.com/dev/likes.add

Answer (score 1):

Вместо строки `driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Нравится')[0].click()`
Попробуйте, следующее `driver.find_element_by_class_name("like_button_icon").click()`